# React : ignore the onClick event when scrolling-y

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angularjs, event-handling

I'm using the `embla-carousel` plugin to create a carousel and I want to ignore the onClick event, which links to another page, when I scroll horizontally.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the Embla opt-in method named `embla.clickAllowed()`. I don't know if you're using the VanillaJS or ReactJS version of Embla. Anyhow, example usage looks something along these lines:

```
const onSlideClick = useCallback((index) => {
  if (!embla || !embla.clickAllowed()) return

  // Embla says the pointer interaction was a static click, and not a drag move.
  // Do your magic here...
}, [embla])
```

```
<div className="embla__container">
  {slides.map((slide, index) => {
    <div className="embla__slide" onClick={() => onSlideClick(index)}>
      ...
    </div>
  })}
</div>
```

##### How it works under the hood

If the pointer is **touch**, Embla will:

- Prevent a click when the gesture is a drag move.
- Prevent clicks when the carousel is clicked during scroll.

If the pointer is **mouse**, Embla will:

- Prevent a click when the gesture is a drag move.
- Not prevent clicks when the carousel is clicked during scroll.

The reason behind this design choice is that touch pointers scroll the document. And when the document is natively scrolling on touch devices, it prevents clicks until the user stops the scrolling and clicks again when it's settled.

But mouse pointers are not used to scroll the document, unless you're dragging the scrollbar. And if you're dragging the scroll bar, it will prevent you from accidentally clicking anything on the webpage anyway, because the pointer is within the scroll bar area. So the assumption here is that we can be more certain that a click with a mouse pointer is intentional.

**Links**

- API reference for `embla.clickAllowed()` [here](https://www.embla-carousel.com/api/methods/#clickallowed).
- A guide on how to implement click events with Embla on the documentation website [here](https://www.embla-carousel.com/guides/click-events/).